# Nginx reverse proxy works internal but not external

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

for accessing some internal servers over the net we have a reverse proxy created.
There I want to proxy pass some traffic to a development server for some external reviewers.

The configuraion works perfect as long as you are connected to the network. 
As soon as you get off and access it on the mobile with 4G you get an error.

Here's my configuration.

```
server {
    listen 193.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl;
    server_name dev.mycompany.site;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      mycompany.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  mycompany.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    server_tokens off;

    access_log logs/mycompany.access.log;
    error_log logs/mycompany.error.log;        

    location / {
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header            Host http_host;                                                                                                                     
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                                    
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header            CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
        recursive_error_pages       on;

        auth_basic                  "RESTRICTED AREA";
        auth_basic_user_file        passwd;

        proxy_pass                  http://192.168.133.7:8081/myapp/;
    }
}
```

As error on external devices I just get a 504 Gateway Timeout.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is fixed.
Issue happened because ict did not properly config the load balancer.